# How to use android accelerometer in flash using AIR for android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am testing out the accelerometer and I tried using the default AIR for Android example and am now trying to make my own game in flash. I copied off of the example's code:

```
    import flash.events.Event;

var accelX:Number;
var accelY:Number;

var fl_Accelerometer:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
fl_Accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler);
function fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
{
    accelX = event.accelerationX;
    accelY = event.accelerationY;
}

ball.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
function moveBall(evt:Event){
    ball.x -= accelX*30;
    ball.y += accelY*30;

    if(ball.x > (480-ball.width/2)){
        ball.x = 480-ball.width/2;
    }
    if(ball.x < (0+ball.width/2)){
        ball.x = 0+ball.width/2;
    }
    if(ball.y > (800-ball.width/2)){
       ball.y = 800-ball.width/2;
    }
    if(ball.y < (0+ball.width/2)){
        ball.y = 0+ball.width/2;
    }
```

I keep on getting this error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 6   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Accelerometer.
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 6   1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Accelerometer.
```

I know I am making a huge novice error but I would really appreciate some help, thank you for who ever took the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the Accelerometer class: `import flash.sensors.Accelerometer`.
Be sure to publish as Android Air project!

Answer (score 1):

This maybe able to help you :)
http://www.flashandmath.com/mobile/anglemeasure/